# Change Magento time before automatic cancellation order

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We have a problem in our shop. Our order is automaticly canceled after 7 days (see printscreen and we want to change the time before automatic cancel.

One of our orders had to wait for a payment update from Paypal. The payment was not accepted immediately and he did after 9 days. Our payment provider gave us a payment update that day, but the order was already cancelled at day 7, so he could not get the status update.

Does anyone know how to change the time before a automatic cancellation?

In the image below you see the status updates:

You will see the customer is redirected to the payment provider.
Then two times Waiting for payment
The third is the automatic cancellation
In the last update the payment provider tries to update the status
Would be great if someone can help!

[image]

Comment: This is not a standard magento functionality. Orders are not canceled automatically unless you have a custom extension for this. If you do, check in System->Configuration for the extension settings.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In this case it was a order that is placed with Paypal via Buckaroo and the order has status waiting for Payment. You do not think this is normal behavior for Magento when a Paypal order is on hold?

Comment: What would normally happen with a order with status waiting for Payment?

Comment: From what I know Magento does not cancel orders on its own. If an order is in Pending status it will remain so until an invoice is created or until someone cancels it or puts it on hold.

Comment: I have just looked at the standard order status that Magento has and here I think it is pending paypal or pending payment and if you are correct about pending status these also should not cancel auotmatic right?

Comment: Like I said...from what I know there is not auto cancelation. I may be wrong. I didn't work that much with Paypal, but I've worked a lot with Magento and this is the first time I hear about this.

Comment: @Marius The same thing is happening for me also, I am using Payubiz, if the order status is Pending, then it get auto cancelled from Magento after 2 or 3 days. Even I am also confused, this is happening 1st time for. Even I have not installed any 3rd Party extension or any cron job.

Comment: @VaibhavDass. You just said you are using "Payubiz". Isn't that a 3rd party extension?

Comment: @Marius I have checked after disabling the same extension. Still, the issue is coming.